# Why does 'The Reasoned Schemer' add an 'o' to the end of its functions?

Tags: scheme, minikanren, reasoned-schemer

In the reasoned schemer, they name standard lisp functions with an 'o' on the end, eg `conso` and `appendo`.

My question is: **Why does 'The Reasoned Schemer' add an 'o' to the end of its functions?**

Comment: Because they are not the same thing. How would you use `cons` and `conso` in the same scope? This is just the 'scheme' the authors of kanren decided on.

Comment: They are not the standard Lisp functions, and superscripting isn't widely supported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From page 2 of  http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~eholk/papers/sfp2012.pdf:

> ```
> It is conventional in Scheme for the names of predicates to
> end with the ‘?’ character. We have therefore chosen to end the
> names of miniKanren goals with a superscript o, which is meant
> to resemble the top of a ?. The superscript e in conde
> stands for
> ‘every,’ since every conde clause may contribute answers.
> ```

Comment: Also note that adding the o makes the names pronounceable.

Comment: I always thought it was because minikanren was a dialect of Esperanto.

Also it makes Conso The Magnificent sound like a Muppet.